# How to use state callback function equivalent on Hooks

Tags: reactjs

I'm basically new to this react hook things, and I'm quite a bit confused. I know that react don't immediately update the state every time setState is called, but the setState method on the class-based component has a callback, which will be called after the state updated. I'm looking for a similar thing on Hook but found nothing yet.

Comment: you can use `useEffect` with the part of the state in question in the dependency argyment

Comment: Please spend a bit more time elaborating on this and potentially including a code example of what you're after. As it is, I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what it is you're asking.

Comment: @zzzzBov my apology, it just me learning something new. I'm not doing any code yet. I ask this because I had the same problem with useState before. I'm not really good at English too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `useEffect` hook to call a function whenever a value is updated

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

useEffect(() => {
   console.log('Print updated value and do some processing here', value);
}, [value]);
```

Comment: can I use multiple useEffect on the same component?

Comment: yes you can. Use as many as you need. You can pass multiple values as dependency to single `useEffect` as well but if logic is different then it is better to use separate useEffect hook